# WPF - Weird results with DataGrid - extra line for editing entries

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Working with WPF and C#. I have a page with a datagrid that lists a series of objects with List as the DataContext. I recently had it working in the code behind and the Datagrid would show the extra line at the bottom of the datagrid for new entries. Now, I have moved the exact same code to its own library project. The data still appears but the extra line for entry does not and users cannot add a new record.

I have already tried using **grid.CanUserAddNew = true;** but that does not solve it. So, it must be something in the List object - it's the exact same code as before, only pulling from a library.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that the extra line is still there but is not visible.

could you make sure the hight and widths are ok.

also what other options attributes do you have defined for the grid?

Comment: Yeah, I considered that too but I have verified all the items and the grid is fine. Again, this was working just fine, it was only until the method that created the List object was moved to a library that this started happening. It has to be something with how the List is being created/called.

The grid itself does not have many properties set. I only bind the List to the DataContext